# How to mount bootbank from ESXi installation disk

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have an ESXi 4.1 server at work.  While playing with getting APC shutdown to work, I modified my /bootbank/oem.tgz so on reboot /.ssh/ would be recreated using the method described on [this page](http://www.blasterspike.it/2011/04/07/how-to-script-to-shutdown-esxi-free-via-an-usb-ups-monitoring-tool/).  In the process, I created a corrupt oem.tgz which prevented the server from booting up correctly.  I saved a copy of the original as oem.tgz.bak before copying my new version over.

So what I need to know is how can I mount /bootbank from within the installation media so I can delete my corrupt copy and rename the original so my server will boot back up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be the installation media ? A Linux [LiveCD](http://www.livecdlist.com/) would probably be much easier. Then use `fdisk -l` to list the devices/partitions and work from there.

Comment: I ended up using an Ubuntu server disc to mount /dev/sda5 and do the edit.  Thanks.